My issue : There was an issue setting up your call Status code 400 { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Bad Request" }
About Oauth2.0, I retrieve the code correctly with my client identifier, the uri, the scope and the prompt=consent but it does not work and i got this error message :
There was an issue setting up your call.

Raw response for the API 
Status code 400
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}


I display the GOOGLE consent page : https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=%5BRedirect_Uri%5D&response_type=code&client_id=%5BXXXXMyIdClientXXX%5D&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets&prompt=consent
And then I get the code in the url and i try to use it :
client_id=[My_ClientId]&client_secret=[My_Client_Secret]&redirect_uri=[my_redirect_uri]&grant_type=authorization_code&code=<code>
I tried lots of things, I still get this error:
There was an issue setting up your call.

Raw response for the API 
Status code 400
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}

What did I forget?
I tried to delete my Oauth ID, it worked one time. I changed nothing and it didn't work at the second time, i found that very strange...
Do you meet this problem ??
